# How to change border color of buttons in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to change the color of the borders of the buttons in tkinter.

I tried : `tk.Button.config(highlightbackground=COLOR)`

but it says **TypeError: configure() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'**

also, I want to make the border color using hex color codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the border color of buttons in tkinter. `highlightbackground` isn't for the border, it's for the highlight ring which lets you know when the widget has keyboard focus.

Comment: my main idea was putting a background color for the window and I wanted to put tiny spaces between buttons so I thought changing borders color to the background color was a great idea. so is there anything I can do to get the same result

Comment: @AhmedMohsen: just add padding between the buttons and the background will show through.